# Idiomatic way to update a record before serving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm working on a RoR application that, when answering on a GET /resource needs to attempt an update of all the resources, taking the data from an external service.
To make things more clear, the pseudocode is:

```
def show
  resource = find_resource
  call_external(resource: resource)
  resource = find_resource
  render
end
```

Now, this would work, but I really really dislike the double find. It's definitely legit as the tech spec is literally to get the resource, use it's attributes to define a from to range of resources to update (which might contain the current one) and get the resource again, still, quite ugly.

Any suggestion on how to refactor this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you get by with calling resource.reload to re-fetch the attributes from the database?

Comment: @JacobEvanShreve is that actually any different, or just slightly more idiomatic?

Comment: If `call_external` could keep that record in sync you wouldn't need to reload.

Comment: It updates several records

Comment: @maxpleaner It depends on how the first find works. When reload is called, it has the id so it can do a `where id = $id` lookup. If the first find does the same thing, then they are effectively the same and will run the same SQL.

Comment: As an aside, if `call_external` is slow you should consider re-architecting this action towards a more async flow where you would return an empty-ish answer from the get, while triggering an async job for the external call. After this, the frontend could poll or the backend could signal the frontend when it's time to do a refresh of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reload` method to update AR object

```
def show
  resource = find_resource
  call_external(resource: resource)
  resource.reload
  render
end
```